# time delta in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Have a question regarding how to create a day count type of column in pandas. Given a list of dates, I want to be able to calculate the difference from one date to the previous date in days. Now, I can do this with simple subtraction and it will return me a timedelta object I think. What if I just want an integer number of days. Using .days seems to work with two dates but I can't get it work with a column.

Let's say I do,

```
df['day_count'] = (df['INDEX_DATE'] - df['INDEX_DATE'].shift(1))
```

`INDEX_DATE  day_count
0   2009-10-06  NaT
1   2009-10-07  1 days
2   2009-10-08  1 days
3   2009-10-09  1 days
4   2009-10-12  3 days
5   2009-10-13  1 days`

I get '1 days'....I only want 1.

I can use .day like this which does return me a number, but it won't work handling an entire column.

```
(df['INDEX_DATE'][1] - df['INDEX_DATE'][0]).days
```

If I try something like this:

```
df['day_count'] = (df['INDEX_DATE'] - df['INDEX_DATE'].shift(1)).days
```

I get an error of
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

I can work around '1 days' but I'm thinking there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: you want `df['day_count'] = (df['INDEX_DATE'] - df['INDEX_DATE'].shift(1)).dt.days`

Comment: Thanks, this and MaxU's solution works!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [197]: df['day_count'] = df.INDEX_DATE.diff().dt.days

In [198]: df
Out[198]:
  INDEX_DATE  day_count
0 2009-10-06        NaN
1 2009-10-07        1.0
2 2009-10-08        1.0
3 2009-10-09        1.0
4 2009-10-12        3.0
5 2009-10-13        1.0
```